# Programmatically manage references window in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn, code-analysis, microsoft.codeanalysis

I created a VSIX package in order to find a list of methods implementations having a certain parameter type (using Roslyn and code analysis API). At this time I jump to a certain file location in solution. Using :

```
ws = componentModel.GetService<VisualStudioWorkspace>();
ws.TryGoToDefinition(mySymbol, myProject, cancelToken);
```

The thing is I have many symmbols I would like to display to user, using the same *'references' window* that gets displayed when pressing Shift + F12 keys. Or a similar approach.

Has anyone got examples or link to code samples ?

Comment: Please post your findings if you do find something.  I was trying to figure out how to plug into existing visual studio windows as well.